# Using 'SET' to get the result of an expression

Tags: cmd, command-line

I am running a Selenium test script through command line which should return a '0' or a '1' exit code based on the success/failure of the test.

However, I am not able to use the SET command to set this return value and assign it to a variable.

When I run

```
Run.bat -project_location "%ProjectLocation%" %RUN_PROP% -latest_exe_status
```

in command line, I get 0 - which is expected.

However when I run

```
SET STATUS=Run.bat -project_location "%ProjectLocation%" %RUN_PROP% -latest_exe_status
echo %STATUS%
```

I get - Run.bat -project_location "%ProjectLocation%" %RUN_PROP% -latest_exe_status

i am pretty sure I am missing something very trivial but I couldn't somehow figure out what I am missing! This is driving me crazy.

Comment: What is returned when you execute `echo %Errorlevel%` after your `Run.bat ...` command line?

Comment: Unfortunately it is always 0

Comment: What happens if you do `Run.bat ... && (echo zero) || (echo non-zero)`? Or does `Run.bat` just display (echo) the result in the console? if so, then this is not the [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_code)...

Answer (score 0):

Just set the STATUS variable from the exit code.

```
Run.bat -project_location "%ProjectLocation%" %RUN_PROP% -latest_exe_status
SET "STATUS=%ERRORLEVEL%"

ECHO The STATUS is %STATUS%
```

Answer (score 0):

The %ERRORLEVEL% after running the Run.bat is always 0 so that didn't help me.

However this did,

```
SET "STATUS=RRun.bat -project_location "%ProjectLocation%" %RUN_PROP% -latest_exe_status"
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`%STATUS%`) DO (SET result=%%F)
echo %result%
```